# android CellSignalStrength

Tags: android

[CellSignalStrength](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrength.html) is a new API  class in android.

It's release on API Level 17.

How to get this cell service signal strength in Android?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use one of those classes:

- [CellSignalStrengthCdma](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthCdma.html)
- [CellSignalStrengthGsm](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthGsm.html)
- [CellSignalStrengthLte](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellSignalStrengthLte.html)

I've played with it, so here is my code:

```
final TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
CellInfoGsm cellInfoGsm = (CellInfoGsm) telephonyManager.getAllCellInfo().get(0);
CellSignalStrengthGsm cellSignalStrengthGsm = cellInfoGsm.getCellSignalStrength();
cellSignalStrengthGsm.getDbm();
```